# Как добраться до дочернего элемента, если родитель не является элементом?

Tags: html, delphi, dom

Пытаюсь добраться до 6 уровня дочерних элементов, но возникает проблема. 5 уровень - это не элемент. То есть у 4 уровня нет дочерних элементов. Дословно 5 уровень `"#document"`.

Старался оформить его как документ, но выходит ошибка, что метод не поддерживается.

`chelement4` - это и есть элементы 4 уровня

```
doc := chelement4.document as IHTMLDocument2;
DocSch := doc.all as IHTMLElementCollection;
for inde := 0 to DocSch.Length - 1 do
begin
  Elementhtm := DocSch.item(inde, 0) as IHTMLElement;
  memo1.lines.Add('дочерние 5ый уровень ' + Elementhtm._classname + Elementhtm.tagName);
end;
```

Comment: Как это не является элементом? Пример документа в студию!

Comment: http://prnt.sc/dv80po

Comment: @Zavet там даже стрелочка стоит, показывая что можно развернуть :)

Comment: @Zavet, а если вас не пускают внутрь #document, значит это у вас кросдоменное обращение, т.к. #document содержит контент фрейма

Comment: В javascript доступ к документу внутри фрейма получают так ` `var frameDocument = document.getElementById('myframe').contentWindow.document`. Ищите аналог функции `contentWindow` в дельфи. И фрейм само собой должен быть загружен. Понятия не имею загружает ли дельфи фреймы.

Comment: @Sergey Загрузка документа и всего сопутствующего ведется через стандартный IWebBrowser2, т.е. "встраиваемый" IE. Сам Delphi имеет в вопросе минимальное участие (просто нужен ответ на этом языке), основное - это как работать с IWebBrowser2 из WinAPI, чтобы достать этот 6 уровень.

Comment: Это не является 6-ым или каким-то ещё уровнем. Это отдельный документ. Надо проверять, является ли текущий элемент фреймом. Если да, то у него есть свойство clientWindow, через которое можно выйти на этот документ. Изучите API DOM и WebBrowser2 более глубоко.